# Searching function of an array from CSV VB.net

Tags: vb.net

So i made part of a function that reads all the names in a CSV file and inputs it to the screen but now i need to make it so the user can input a name to search for and if it is in the CSV file then it will tell them the name is in the file.
here's what i have so far:

Names in the CSV:

```
    jack
    tom
    jeff
    bill
    bob
```

Reads the names in the csv:

```
Dim location As String = "C:\Users\626284\Desktop"
    Dim files As String = "names.csv"
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(location, files))
    System.Array.Sort(lines)

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines))
```

Search for the name:
Havent worked this part out. Basically the program has to say

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a name you would like to search for")
search = Console.ReadLine()
If search = lines
then 
Console.WriteLine("Name is found")
ElseIf 
Console.WriteLine("Name isnt found")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a name you would like to search for")
Dim search = Console.ReadLine()
If lines.Any(Function(line) line = search) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Name is found")
ElseIf 
    Console.WriteLine("Name isnt found")
End If
```

Comment: hey, thanks this works, i was just wondering if i wanted to loop this process so that the screen would write "Would you like to search for a new name" and the user would decide if they want to put another name in they could, how would i do this ?

Comment: @huntermcc - Look up a `While` loop.